# Black Macbook and 6 GB RAM

Tags: memory, macbook, upgrade

I have a 2.4 Ghz Macbook running 4 GB RAM. Some companies sell 4 GB chips to upgrade to 6 GB RAM. Has this ever caused problems? I am running VMWare Fusion and the extra RAM would be a big help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Apple's supported maximum is 4GB, but according to [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca/) and [Other World Computing](http://macsales.com/), the hardware and software does support 6GB as a 2GB+4GB combo.

(See http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/5300DDR2S6GP/)

You can probably buy a like 4GB chip on its own if you've already got a 2GB chip installed, but in either case, you're not going to be getting the performance benefit that comes from having a matched pair.

Comment: I've added the 6GB and so far, no problems.